# Where can I find AS3 port of gskinners's collision detection?

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel, collision, detection

Recently, I discovered Grant Skinner's awesome pixel-perfect collision detection package for AS2: [Grant Skinner's AS2 Collision Detection](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2005/10/source_code_sha.html) I also found out there's an AS3 port of it. Does anyone know where I can find it? A number of sites say you can find it here: [AS3 PORT](http://labs.boulevart.be/index.php/2007/06/08/skinner-collision-detection-in-as3/)
But the link is seven years old & no longer works. Any help is appreciated!

Damian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant moved all his libraries, to the GitHub.

[Collision detection](https://github.com/gskinner/AS3Libs/tree/master/CollisionDetection) that you are looking for. I also recommend to star his incomplete AS3 GitHub repository.

Comment: also, might be worth looking at [BitmapData's hitTest for collision detection](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/25/strategies-for-optimizing-collision-detection-with-bitmapdata-hittest/)